# What is the difference between socket.connect(endpoint) and new Socket(ip,port)

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming

When creating client connection to serversocket we can create client sockets in two ways My question is what is the difference between below two approaches,

```
 InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
  SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, 1111); 
  Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
  clientSocket.connect(sockaddr);
```

And the other approach

```
Socket clientSocket=new Socket("localhost",1111);
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They are identical.

The advantage of `new Socket()` is that you can then call the *other* overload of `connect(),` that takes a timeout parameter.

Comment: @shekharsuman The answer to that is in my profile here. No need to ask in other places. Or are you just posting link spam?